# dos opciones para un mismo formulario javascript puro

Tags: javascript

hola quiero saber como hacer una función de JavaScript teniendo 2 botones y que cada botón me llame al mismo formulario, asignándole un id diferente, por ejemplo: hombre y o  mujer, se selecciona y muestra el mismo formulario para ambos solo que deberá identificar si es un hombre o mujer.

```
<div class="row">
<fieldset class="fieldset-default">
<legend align="center">Seleccione Sexo</legend>
<form name="option_tablero" class="option_tablero registro">

<div class="col-6 center"> <input type="radio" id='reg 01' name="tablero" value="pcc1" class="big" onclick="opciones(1)"/>MASCULINO</div>
<div class="col-6 center"> <input type="radio" id='reg 02' name="tablero" value="pcc2" class="big" onclick="opciones(2)"/>FEMENINO</div>

</form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

al dar clic en opción masculino y o femenino debe mandar a un formulario el cual es igual para ambos pero el javascript debe definir si el id es de masculino o femenino

Comment: también quiero saber como puedo ir cambiando el id de un Div

Comment: No termina de quedar claro del todo a qué te refieres con eso de enviar a un formulario con un id diferente. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que quieres y lo que has intentado?

Comment: Y aparte, dos comentarios: los id no deben contener espacios en blanco (lo que hace que el código HTML compartido no sea válido y puede dar problemas al operar con él en JavaScript); y que haya que cambiar el id de un elemento para que funcione el programa suele ser una señal de que algo no está bien diseñado (aunque esto puede ser un malentendido al no quedarme clara la pregunta).

Comment: <script>
  function CambiarEstilo() {
      var elemento = document.getElementById("motivo");
      if (elemento.className == "tipo1") {
        elemento.className = "tipo2";
      }else {
        elemento.className = "tipo1";
      }
  }
  </script>// este código me cambia la clase quiero que cambie el id

Comment: ¿qué es exactamente el código del comentario? Usa clases/ids (motivo, tipo1, tipo2) que no están en el código compartido en la pregunta. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para añadir un ejemplo completo del código.